# How to export all elements in a iPhone WhatsApp chat?

Tags: iphone, backup, whatsapp.app

I need to export all contents in a WhatsApp chat, going back several months, including lots of audio and other media. This is for legal reasons, thus **I absolutely need each and every element in the conversation**. WhatsApp is running on a iPhone 5s, the phone is synchronized with iTunes on a Windows PC, and all elements in the chat have never been deleted.

I tried using WhatsApp's "email chat" function, but it skipped several media, probably due to message size limits (the email was exactly 10 MB); unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an option in WhatsApp to split the log into multiple emails.

I have an iTunes backup and I can perform an iCloud backup; however, I don't know how to extract WhatsApp data from them. There seem to be lots of apps out there for extracting this kind of data, but they are not free (and I also don't know if they work as promised); I'd prefer a free solution, but a paid one is ok if it can fulfill my requirements.

I already wrote to WhatsApp support, and I'm waiting for their reply; however, I'm also asking here, maybe someone can help.

Comment: http://www.i-funbox.com/ is free, works with OS X and Windows; I'm not sure if Whatsapp data will be visible / usable.

Comment: It doesn't work, it complains about WhatsApp not supporting "iTunes File Sharing" (http://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/13/ios-8-3-ifunbox-itools-sandbox-app-access)

Comment: You might be able to contact WhatsApp and ask them to send you a .zip of the chat, and explain to them that you need it for legal reasons.

Comment: CopyTrans Contacts is a paid app that might do the trick as it can export in several different formats (html, txt, xls to name a few): http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-backup-whatsapp-messages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CopyTrans Contacts](http://www.copytrans.net/copytranscontacts.php) is an application which can export WhatsApp chats in several formats, including HTML pages and Word documents with intenal links to attachments; this allows easy and comfortable reviewing of the exported chats.

CopyTrans Contacts is not free, but a limited trial is available; the trial allows up to 50 actions to be performed, and a full export of a WhatsApp chat counts as a single action; therefore, the trial version is more than enough for exporting the full contents of one or more chats.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (2023) you can go to the chat, tap on the name of the contact or  the group, scroll all the way down and then tap on "Export chat". You will be asked if you want to attach media or export only the text. It will then create a .zip compressed file that you can share in any way you want (add to a cloud file service, AirDrop, send by email, etc).

Answer (score -1):

To recover your chat history from an iCloud backup, first verify that an iCloud backup exists in **WhatsApp Settings > Chats and Calls > Chat Backup**. If you can see when the last backup was performed, delete and reinstall the app from the App Store. After verifying your phone number, follow the on-screen prompts to restore your chat history. The same iCloud backup requirements apply for iCloud restore. In addition, the phone number used for backing up and restoring must be the same. http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/20888066

Comment: ...and what exactly does this have to do with *exporting* the chat contents?!?

Comment: I was just trying to help.